# Render camera preview in Chrome using Native Client SDK

Tags: camera, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient, ppapi

I'm trying to write **ppapi plugin** for Chrome which will use  **webcam** (show **preview** and write file). I have installed NaCl sdk with **pepper_35**. 
There available examples in /examples/api/ folder: *media_stream_audio* and  *media_stream_video*.

The audio example works fine - requests access to microphone and shows some kind of preview.

The **"media_stream_video"** example must show web-camera video preview, but when I load example on the local web server (with *make serve* command), there appears red rect, and Chrome asks for the web camera access. When I click “allow” - webcam indicator lights-up, chrome show that web page uses the web camera, and I see the camera settings icon. But the preview doesn't work, there still red rectangle instead.

I checked this on  Windows 8.1, Windows 7 and Mac OS X, with five different webcams, and have no idea what can be wrong.

Maybe someone already encountered with the same problem?

Comment: Show us the relevant code.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you running? Are you running stable/beta/canary? Is there any output in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I use Chrome 37.0.2062.120 m (it's stable version) and pepper_35 NaCl SDK (currently it is the latest stable version). The JavaScript console is empty when I work with this video sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the pepper_37(dev) version of NaCl SDK solved the problem. Looks like it is unstable version currently, but it works.