# Is it possible to access microphone from NaCl/PPAPI?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, audio, google-nativeclient, ppapi

I am doing a feasibility study for a PPAPI plugin. One of must-have requirements is access to the microphone to enabled audio recording.

I have found API to [play audio](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/audio), but not to record it.
Several post suggest that it can't be done:

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/native-client-discuss/Hj1oOMjYmgk/YlAtdYfXXToJ
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/native-client-discuss/Sm5Lq1C4fTs

However those posts are quite outdated and in [PPAPI release notes from Feb 20 of 2014](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/sdk/release-notes#chrome-pepper-34-20-feb-2014) it's mentioned that an [audio input API](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_dev/cpp/classpp_1_1_media_stream_audio_track) was added in dev. 
I was unable to find any tutorial for the matter, nor the confirmation that this API is now in stable release.

So my question is: can audio input be done from PPAPI, if so, is there any further documentation, except the code and a "dry" summary on doc page?

Comment: See this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746675/render-camera-preview-in-chrome-using-native-client-sdk

Comment: I'm curious to know if you ever received an answer for this

Comment: @Smalesy, never. The project was closed and have not continued my research.